# Scraping Uber service coverage from Uber City website into shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, polygon, web-service, uber

I would like to get a full national wide coverage of Uber service area. I find there are specific coverage boundaries by city on its website. For example, https://www.uber.com/cities/charlotte/.

Is there a way extract the polygon and turn it into a shapefile?

If so, is it possible to scale it up for all the cities?

Comment: view source on https://www.uber.com/en-US/cities/charlotte/ do a find for 'geobox' and then the next 'geojson' will be the coordinates - copy out in a text editor and save as geojson (check formatting is correct) load into qgis and export as shapefile. (this might be against the terms of use - I am not a lawyer)

Comment: Have you asked Uber whether they are willing to supply you with this data?

Comment: Scraping is a bit archaic.  I'd first try to see if they expose something in the [Uber API](https://developer.uber.com/).  I'd search for GeoFence.  See interesting article [here](https://eng.uber.com/go-geofence/).

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks very much! Now I can see and extract lat/lng in the source code. But the same method seem not apply to Lyft (e.g. https://www.lyft.com/rider/cities/auburn-al ) Do you have any suggestion in this case?

Comment: That is not uber but lyft (technically a different question) you need to use the api for that https://www.lyft.com/api/region/auburn-al (has all the info you need)

Comment: @Mapperz Incredible!This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!